# Prevent bookmarklet to be executed on page

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I sometimes use Print What You Like service via bookmarklet http://www.printwhatyoulike.com/bookmarklet Today I noticed that it does not work on this page http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/howto-change-runlevel-on-grub2/ Is there any possibility that author of the page can prevent using bookmarklets on his page?

Comment: Not unless they are "blocking" a specific bookmarklet by screwing it up, which shouldn't happen if it was designed correctly.

Comment: How can they block specific bookmarklet? It is all client-side scripting, or am I missing something? By "screwing it up" you mean that they block service (bookmarklet) accidentally? PS: sorry for my English.

Comment: For example, if they screwed up some global variable that was used, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested in Firefox, runs fine.

Yes, there are ways to prevent most bookmarklets from running. The methods are designed to reduce cross site script security exploits, but bookmaklets can suffer as collateral damage. However that site does not appear to be using any such methods.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy (also, don't forget to accept my answer please.)